# Push notifications to app users ( android ) when firebase database changes?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am using Firebase as backend for my android app.I Need a solution to send notifications to app users on either firebase data change . How shall I achieve this? 
Thanks .

Comment: Consider using Cloud Functions for Firebase to write a database trigger. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: Can you please describe what have you tried implemented so far so we  can help you

Comment: @DougStevenson how can i send push notifications using database trigger ?

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed I have tried the examples in OneSignal documentation as well as Firebase cloud messaging for sending push notifications manually to user devices using notifications composer

Comment: @SofieneMabrouk First you need to create a topic and then make the  user that will be  receiving push notification  subscribe to that topic , then you use  Firebase Databse trigger to send a push notification  to that topic on database changes .

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed Do you have any documentation or an example for the solution that you suggested ?

Comment: @SofieneMabrouk you can try this link https://aaronczichon.de/2017/03/13/firebase-cloud-functions/ . I have not tried it but it looks promising